# Prestashop getting front-office transtation item from controller

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im using prestashop 1.6

Is there a way to get translation string from front-office translations in controller?

My task is to add on store page (StoreController.php, strores.tpl are responsible for this) translation for word "Closed" in shop work schedule.
So i decided to add in template

`{* 
   {l s='Closed'}
*}`

but cant find the way to use it in controller.

Of course it is possible to use this translation directly in tpl, but there is passing from controller already prepared schedule, so it is just more work to do in this way.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $this->l('Your variable') in your controllers and it is absolutely the same as {l s='Your variable'} in the template file.

Comment: `$this->l('Your variable')` method available in modules, but not in controllers